# add permissions to launch the simulator GUI from Docker compose xhost + local:root

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on windows and following some instructions to deploy a docker app.

To start the simulator, first, you need to add permissions to launch the simulator GUI from Docker compose:

```bash
xhost + local:root
```

I put the command (`host + local:root`) in the console where the directory of the YAML file is but does not work.

How should I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new terminal, then you can use the command xhost + local:root.

Or you can use the command:

```
xhost +local:`docker inspect --format='{{ .Config.Hostname }}' `docker ps -q`
```